# Exclude directory from Tuckey rewrite filter

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using tuckey to rewrite URLs:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z-/]+)$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>]
```

However..I have a webservice servlet hosted at:

```
/ws/service
```

How do I exclude that from Tuckey rewriting? With the existing rule this will forward the request to /ws/service.xhtml which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following rule:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/ws/.*$</from>
    <to  last="true">-</to>
</rule>
```